# Buddypress: Why upload avatars not work

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I install `Buddypress` in my site, And when any user register in my site and try to change his avatars, He cannot show the button to do that

I see this link but not work ...

How can solve this error

[BuddyPress codex link](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/guides/customizing-buddypress-avatars/)

Answer (score 0):

Please select the checkbox form Dashboard -> Settings -> Buddypress-> Setting -> Profile Settings.
Select Profile Photo Uploads: Allow registered members to upload avatars.